# Perform a CAT in FOR and SSH

Tags: bash

I do not have much experience in shell script, therefore I need your help. I have the following query, I need to make a CAT to the files that I list, but I have not managed to know where to place the command. Thank you:

```
read date
echo  -e  "RECORDINGS"

for e in $Rec
   do
   sshpass -p password ssh user@server find $e "-type f -mtime -10 -exec ls -gGh --full-time {} \;" | cut -d ' ' -f 4,7 | grep $date | awk -F " " '{print $2}'
done
```

Comment: Trying to put complex commands in an `ssh` command can be very difficult, because of nested quotes and escaping. Can you put a shell script on the server and run that instead?

Comment: Passing the script as a heredoc is another approach that would be less error-prone.

Comment: BTW, if you want to find a file created at a certain time, it's far *far* safer to let `find` do that comparison for you; [parsing `ls` is innately error-prone](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). See the `-newerXY` operation in GNU `find`; with `-newermt`, for example, you could ask `find` to find a file that's newer than a very specific timestamp passed as a subsequent argument, and then follow that with a `! -newermt` to tell it to *ignore* things newer than the end of whatever your target range is.

Comment: It is a fragment of the code, this is inside a .sh, and is executed on the server. Thanks for the help

Comment: Also note that passing passwords on a command line lets every other process on the server view them, at least for an instant before the newly-started command is able to rewrite its argument list. For that reason, `sshpass` should be given values through the environment, not on the command line.

Comment: (Also, `for e in $Rec` should generally be rewritten to make `Rec` an array, not a string, which is then iterated over with `for item in "${array[@]}"` -- that way you don't get an element of `*` replaced with a list of files in the current directory, for example, or get a directory named `/Users/Name With Spaces/` split into `/Users/Name`, `With` and `Spaces` as three separate items).

Comment: ...on the above point, see [DontReadLinesWithFor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), and [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: As another note, it's best to avoid the `-e` argument to `echo` -- the POSIX specification explicitly says that *Implementations shall not support any options*, and then makes an exception only for `-n`, leaving any implementation where `-e` doesn't print the string `-e` on output noncompliant. Yes, GNU is a major offender on this one (though even they disable that functionality and become compliant with the correct runtime flags set), but the safe practice is to switch to `printf`, which works consistently everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring that much of the code here is outright dangerous --

```
find_on_server() {
  local e_q
  printf -v e_q '%q ' "$1"
  sshpass -p password ssh user@server "bash -s $e_q" <<'EOF'
    e=$1
    find "$e" -type f -mtime -10 -exec ls -gGh --full-time {} \;
EOF
# ^^^ the above line MUST NOT BE INDENTED
}

find_on_server "$e" | cut -d ' ' -f 4,7 | grep $date | awk -F " " '{print $2}'
```